# Git local branch update on remote without all commit history

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a local development branch that is tracking origin/development.

Both have same commits for their HEAD.

Now, I've checked-out development branch into a new branch (task1) and made 20 commits over few weeks.

If I do "git merge task1" on development branch. I get all the 20 commits now in my development branch which I don't want to push to origin/development.

I want origin/development to have all my 20 commits shown as a single commit that says "Implemented Task 1"

How can I acheieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these techniques can be found in the Git book under the topic "[Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)". Note: All of them are somewhat dangerous, so until you feel confident with what you're doing, you may want to create a second clone of your local repo (you can directly clone your local repo with a different name) and then try your commands.

If something goes wrong, simply clone again.

When you have something that works, write down the commands and delete your second clone.

The command which you're looking for is `rebase` with the option `--interactive`. In the editor, you can pick commits and "squash" them:

> s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit

Related:

- [squashing commits with rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)